# Cannot get more than 3 Webcams to work at once (in OBS)

Tags: usb, webcam, obs-studio

I have 1 Logitech C290, and 4 C270s, but I can only ever get a max of three working at the same time in OBS Studio.

I've tried pretty much every combination of hubs and not hubs, powered hubs, PCI-E USB ports. I can definitely see them all, and they all definitely work (especially because if I restart Windows, I get a different 3 that end up being the 3). Plus I can see them all in Windows as webcams with no problem.

There's also some sort-of-sketchy java programs out there that supposedly help, but I'm obviously skeptical.

Is there something more that should be trying? Or something that I'm currently doing wrong?